# Let $f\in C^1[-\pi ,\pi]$ be such that $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$Show that $\{na_n\} $ is convergent to $0$

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Let $f\in C^1[-\pi ,\pi]$ be such that $f(-\pi)=f(\pi)$. Define

$$a_n=\int _{-\pi}^\pi  f(t)\cos nt \, dt, n\in \mathbb N$$

Prove that:

> 1. $\{a_n\}$ is bounded,
> 2. $\{na_n\} $ is convergent to $0$,
> 3. $\sum n^2|a_n|^2$ is convergent.

**Solution**:

Since every continuous function on a compact set is bounded so $|f(x)|\leq M$ which implies that $$|f(x)\cos nx|\leq |f(x)||\cos nx|\leq M \cdot 1 = M$$ is bounded on $[-\pi,\pi]$. Hence $|a_n|\leq |\int _{-\pi}^\pi  f(t)\cos nt \, dt|\leq 2M\pi$.

How should  I go on $2,3$. Practically I am not getting any idea.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** For $2$ use integration by parts and the famous [Riemann-Lebesgue Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Lebesgue_lemma) and for $3$ recall [Bessel's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_inequality).

**Edit1:**  As $f'$ is continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$ implies $f'\in L^2([-\pi,\pi])$, Apply Bessel's Inequality to $f'$ hence
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1} n^2 a_n^2 <+\infty $$

**Edit2:** Recall that we have the (complete) orthonormal trigonometric system (basis) $\;\{u_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;,\;\;u_n=\{1,\sin x,\cos x, \sin 2x,\cos2x,\ldots\}\;$ with which we work in Fourier series, so then denoting by $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ the usual inner product we get(ofcourse using Bessel's inequality)

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f'(x),u_n\rangle^2\le||f'||^2$$

But using the usual notation from Fourier series the above is just

$$||f'||^2\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^2 a_n^2 $$

Note that here we are using that fourier coefficients of $f'$ are $na_n$ which you must have noticed in part $2$.

Comment: to apply Bessel's inequality ;you need an orthonormal sequence $e_i$ such that $x=<x,e_i>e_i$ where are these conditions satisfied here

Comment: Do you mind giving a more detailed answer ; I am not getting it from here ;the hypotheses of the inequality is not satisfied here also